# Близнецы и близняшки – гендерное различие?

Tags: лексика

Несколько лет назад одна моя юная знакомая пришла в непомерное удивление, услышав от меня словосочетание «сёстры-близнецы». По ее мнению близнецами могут быть только  мальчики,  девочек  в таких случаях называют  близняшками. Мои заверения, что суффикс этот  уменьшительно-ласкательный и никакой привязки к полу не имеет, ее не убедили. Я начала прислушиваться к нашим СМИ и обнаружила, что она права: там никогда не называют девочек близнецами, а мальчиков близняшками.  Одно из двух: либо нужно вносить эти новые значения старых слов в словари, либо что-то делать с нашими СМИ.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41732/%d0%98-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что суффикс -***яшк***  выделяется в именах существительных женского рода с ***уменьшительно-ласкательным или только ласкательным значением*** (кудря́шка, морда́шка и т.п.). Поэтому о девочках принято говорить: сестры-близняшки. Однако и ***сестры-близнецы*** тоже не будет считаться ошибкой.

[См.Толковый словарь Ефремовой](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/135926/-%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA-)

Comment: Извините, не совсем вас поняла. По-вашему, этот суффикс всё же имеет отношение к полу?

Comment: Да, это суффикс ж.р.

Comment: >Да, это суффикс ж.р.  

Это не так. Здесь два суффикса. "яш" - ничего гендерного не несущий (племяш, например) и "ка" - который можно отчати признать "гендерным", но тоже не до конца.

Comment: Т.е. для вас существует слово м.р. «близняш»? И тогда ж.р. от него «близняшка»? Просьба к вам и к Сержу: приведите примеры такого словообразования, кроме сущ-х на –ист и случаев чередования –к- и –ч-, т.е. чтобы в чистом виде был женский суффикс -к-.

Comment: Только сейчас увидел. Смысла вопроса не понял. 
1. Про слово "близняш" я ничего не говорил. Совершенно не обязательно должно существовать такое слово, здесь два суффикса "друг без друга" могут и не существовать, но проявляться в других словах. Вот недавно разбирали слово "собственность"... Исторический корень "соб" (ср. "особый"), остальное - нагромождение суффиксов. Но в разговорном языке слово "близняш" конечно же существует.   
2. Что такое ву сичтаом виде - и причем тут "-ист" и "чередование"? "Гражданинин" - "гражданка" подойдет? "Кот" - "кошка"? Короб - коробка Это только парные с м.р.

Comment: @behemothus Гражданин - гражданка не подойдет: отвалилось -ин-, Кот - кошка, моряк- морячка не подходят из-за палатализации. Короб и коробка это не "леди и джентльмен", а неодушевленные объекты. "-ист" тут при том, что это заимствованный суффикс и таких примеров масса: марксист-марксист, активист-активистка, артист-артистка. Если -к- женский суффикс, то при отрезании его должен оставаться м.р.: "близняш". Вы верно заметили, что суффиксы могут проявляться в других словах, вот я и прошу привести примеры этих проявлений.

Comment: Что значит "не пойдет"? Какой критерий того, что вам "подходит"?

>Вы верно заметили, что суффиксы могут проявляться в других словах...
  
Вы меня совершенно не поняли. Я говорил о том, что никакого правила для вычленения суффикса по принципу типа того, что "если его отбросить, то "останется слово" не существует. Если так подходить то то получится в том самом *гражданине* "ин" - не суффикс. Потому, дескать, что если его отбросить, то никакого слова не останется.  
На самом деле суффикс это потому, что он присутвует в других словах и не входит в корень.

Comment: Это не мне не подходит: существуют научные критерии. Если слово «гражданка» образовано от «гражданин», то не только с помощью суффикса –к-, а еще и с помощью замены –ин- на 0. Рыбачка, морячка - помощью суффикса –ьк- иначе откуда палатализация? Наука о языке – точная, для доказательства требуется повторяемость.

Comment: @Серж вот что по вашей ссылке: суффикс; -яшк-(а) 
Формообразовательная единица, образующая
1) имена существительные женского рода с уменьшительно-ласкательным или только с ласкательным значением (кудря́шка, морда́шка и т.п.)
2) имя существительное общего рода с уменьшительно-ласкательным или только с ласкательным значением (дура́шка).

Comment: @Серж  У Ефремовой не сказано, что суффикс –яшк- женского рода  Ведь «морда» и до этого суффикса была женского рода, а «дура́шка» не обрел женский род вместе с суффиксом. («какой дура́шка!»), значит в самом суффиксе нет ничего специфически женского, у Ефремовой он назван уменьшительно-ласкательным. Меня интересует мотивация людей, почувствовавших потребность в образовании сущ-го ж.р. от слова «близнец» и выбравших для этого «близняшку». Если сможете продолжить парадигму «близнец» - «близняшка» другими примерами- соглашусь с вами во всем.

Answer (score 0):

Она не права.
Близняшка - разговорная форма для "близнец". Чаще используется для женского рода, но совершенно не императивно. 
"Близняшка"  - существительное общего рода, т.е. может относиться и к мужчинам, и к женщинам. 
"Близнец" - строго говоря тоже "общего", просто в грамматической традиции такие слова не относят к общему роду, это мужской род, который может  относится и к женщине. Для сравнения - названия, например, профессий, многие из которых без изменений применяются к женщинам: врач, министр, вахтёр...
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: А кто не прав: я или моя знакомая? Я под вашими словами охотно подпишусь. А моя знакомая права в том, что, когда она росла и впитывала язык из информационной  среды (СМИ составляют ее значительную часть), она точно вычислила, в каком именно значении там употребляют это слово.

Comment: Тина, в словарях слово " близняшки" дается с пометой: м.р. и ж.р. См.,напр., Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов. Однако В словаре Ефремовой говорится, что яшк - суффикс ж.р.Видимо, учитывается традиция.

Comment: Насчет суффикса ж.р. -яшк- дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку и какие-нибудь примеры.

Comment: @Серж  очень интересует суффикс ж.р. -яшк-. В словаре Ефремовой я его не нашла. Будьте любезны, дайте ссылку.

Comment: Тина, ссылку см. под моим ответом.

Comment: Ну и в моем ответе ссылка на суффикс **-ашк-** имеется.

Comment: >А кто не прав: я или моя знакомая?   
  
Знакомая, конечно. Да, по факту в огромном большинстве случаев под близняшкой понимается только девочка (женщина). Но даже единственное исключение, тем более - словарно фиксируемое - уже лишает права говорить в духе исключительности (*только*  девочка).

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкопрусе "сёстры-близнецы" — 16 вхождений, "сёстры-близняшки" — 2 вхождения.

> [БЛИЗНЕЦЫ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8B), -ов; мн. (ед. близнец, -а; м.). 1. Дети, детёныши, рождённые одной матерью одновременно; двойняшки.

Дети, я не мальчики!