# И снова о близнецах

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прочитала вопрос о близнецах и близняшках.
А я еще слышала, что близнецы и двойняшки (тройняшки и т.д.) - это разные вещи. Мол, близнецы - разнояйцевые, то есть, могут быть разного пола и отличаться внешне, а двойняшки - исключительно однояйцевые, то есть, идентичные. И что, мол, называть двойняшек близнецами неграмотно. Правда ли это?

Comment: См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/41596/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вот это как раз интересный вопрос. 
Если сразу дать ответ, то "нет, это неправда".

Можно, конечно, просто посмотреть в словарь - и убедиться, что утверждающие обратное (что близнецы бывают только однояйцевые) неправы. Но попробуем разобраться предметно. Я пропускаю ваше "не совсем научное" изложение сути "однояйцевости" и "разнояйцевости" близнецов, сразу по сути вопроса.

То, что процитировано (Тина) из ответа грамотной "Справки" безусловно правильно. Но это не полный ответ на вопрос. Или даже ответ не совсем на тот вопрос.

В заданном тут вопросе предлагается разрешить ситуацию с правильными названиями для однояйцевых и разнояйцевых близнецов. А двойняшки они или тройняшки - это уже вопрос следующий.

Итак. По пунктам.
Являются ли "близнецами" внешне не похожие друг на друга одновременно родившиеся дети (от многоплодной беременности)? Да, безусловно, что прямо следует из определения "близнецы". Оставляем за скобками известные науки случаи одновременной беременности от разных отцов.

Тем более нет причин сомневаться в том что однояйцевые дети - близнецы.

Являются ли такие дети двойняшками? Да, если их двое, независимо от внешнего сходства.

Таким образом, ни слово "близнецы", ни слово "двойняшки" (тройняшки и т.д.) не несут никакого указания на однояйцевость или разнояйцевость детей.

Оно и понятно. Слова появились задолго до понимания сути многоплодия, его генетической природы. Но вместе с тем, наблюдать за тем, что близнецы бывают как внешне тождественными друг другу, так и совершенно непохожими, люди могли тоже на всём протяжении рода человеческого. Как ни странно, ни в одном из известных языков нет подходящего "бытового" термина для различения этих случаев. Даже современное "однояйцевость" не решает проблемы. Разнояйцевые близнецы могут быть похожи как две капли воды, тогда как однояйцевые различаться в силу особенностей внутриутробного развития (хотя это редкий случай). Видимо, на протяжении веков у народов не было большой необходимости как-то дифференцировать случаи "одинаковых" и "разных" близнецов. В русском языке их всех, видимо, сочли "близкими". Для практических целей куда важнее было сказать, сколько их там родилось. Отсюда и все эти "двойни", "тройни" и даже "четверни". Про "пятерни" и "шестерни" в давние века, видимо, не слышали, это уже следствие современных медицинских практик.

В современном же языке получившийся вакуум в обозначениях часто стремятся заполнить путем переосмысления термина "близнецы": полагая, что имеется в виду "близость" в значении "сходство". А уж из сходства выводят однояйцевость (как уже сказал, не совсем корректно с научной точки зрения). Возможно, когда-нибудь такой подход и будет иметь право на существование, но пока словарями он не фиксируется. 
***"Близнецы" по современным представлениям - это все: и разнополые, и разнояйцевые, и непохожие, и двойняшки-тройняшки - лишь бы от одной многоплодной беременности.*** И не только по отношению к людям, всё вполне переносится на всех животных, вплоть до яйцекладущих и даже отдельных рыб - т.е. на всех, имеющих сходные с нашими принципы репродуктивной системы.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно словарям близнецы -  дети, одновременно рождённые одной матерью. Близнецы-двойняшки. Близнецы-тройняшки. Братья-близнецы. Сёстры-близнецы. Однояйцовые близнецы (развивающиеся из одного оплодотворённого яйца; однополые, очень похожие друг на друга). Разнояйцовые близнецы (развивающиеся из разных яиц, возможно разнополые, не во всём похожие друг на друга). 
Двойняшки (разг.) – это два близнеца. 
Таким образом, близнецы могут быть и не двойняшками (а, например, тройняшками), а вот двойняшки – всегда близнецы.
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_174